# Взаимодействие cmd и Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, netcat

Открыты 2 командной строки, одна из них это netcat с полученной сессией, как я могу писать туда команды c помощью Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import pty
import fcntl
import sys
import select
import socket
```

Конект от нетката прининял через accept

```
addr = ("", 5543)
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as sock:
    sock.bind(addr)
    sock.listen(1)
    conn, addr = sock.accept()
    with conn:
```

Снял блокировку с сокета

```
        conn.setblocking(0)
```

Открыл новую консоль

```
        master, slave = pty.openpty()
```

Запустил в этой консоли питон

```
        pid = os.fork() 
        if pid == 0:
            os.setsid()
            os.dup2(slave,0)
            os.dup2(slave,1)
            os.dup2(slave,2)
            os._exit(
                os.execv(sys.executable,(sys.executable,))
                )
```

Снял блокировку с консоли

```
        pipe = os.fdopen(master, 'wb+', buffering=0)
        fl = fcntl.fcntl(master, fcntl.F_GETFL)
        fcntl.fcntl(master, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

В цикле селект выбирает где появились данные, в консоли или в сокете

```
        while True:
            ready_read, _, _ = select.select([pipe, conn],[],[])
            for reader in ready_read:
```

Вычитываю из одного и пишу в другое

```
                if reader == pipe:
                    conn.sendall(pipe.read())
                else:
                    pipe.write(conn.recv(4096))
```

Comment: Такое чувство что мне ответил сам Бог Python'а

Comment: Но почему я получаю ошибку No module named termios?

Comment: Пишут что он работает только в Unix, я просто в windows работаю

Comment: Я в виндовс не знаю как

Comment: @KryptonH ещё на виндовс вроде не работает select. А термиос я вроде не подключал... Какой стек на ошибке?

Comment: Вместо pty и fork можешь попробовать subprocess с пайпами. Селект можно заменить на треды

Comment: вообще я могу выполнить команду при выдаче сессии в самом netcat? (я понимаю вопрос не по теме Python)

Comment: @KryptonH так на socat умею) на неткат не скажу

Comment: понял,спасибо за красивый ответ,без токсичности,благодарен